# How do I handle debugging App freezes and memory leaks?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI MacApp, where I'm trying to replicate the xcode Inspector functionality.

I have the main Layout of the ContentView in a basic HStack using a Divider with a drag gesture to dynamically resize the Inspector something like this:

```
//Pseudocode
HStack {
    Mainview()
    Divider()
        .gesture(dragGesture)
    Inspector()
        .frame(width: widthValue)
}
```

so far so good, the actual gesture works really smooth, but when you play around with it a bit the app freezes (100%cpu). Xcode is not throwing any Errors related to this.

Since I had no clou what to do I started googeling and found surprisingly little on the topic, but I got that I should check with Instruments.
And from what I can tell the App gets stuck redrawing the view over and over, which makes no sense to me, because this happens when you end the gesture.

`TLDR`: my mac app freezes when a drag gesture ends

to reproduce: drag the divider back and forth a couple times, when the gesture ends

expected behaviour: cpu load goes back down

actual behaviour: CPU stuck at 100%, RAM usage steadily increasing

I have no idea where to go from here, so any input is appreciated, you can find my minimal reproducing code [here](https://pastebin.com/Nt10ZKab)

I'm on MacOS 12.5.1 on M1 MacBookAir using XCode 13.4.1

Comment: There is no way to help you specifically since you have provided a reproducible example as code not a link but my guess is you are likely misusing something in SwiftUI I would suggest watching the wwdc videos videos including Demytifying SwiftUI

Comment: so you can't reproduce this behaviour with the code? @loremipsum

Comment: You are supposed to add the code to the question and not as a link and if you have too much code for pasting into the question then you need to find a way to reproduce the problem with less code. Otherwise the question is of little value to anyone else but you.

Comment: Have you tried Self._printChanges() for trouble shooting? Here two article’s related to that command and SwiftUI debugging, https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/debugging-swiftui-views/ and https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-find-which-data-change-is-causing-a-swiftui-view-to-update

Comment: I agree with @JoakimDanielson that code to reproduce the produce the problem should be included in the question, preferably distilled down to the minimum necessary to reproduce.  But I did read at the code at the link.  It looks like your gesture is sending `changeInspectorWidth` to your view model which is `@EnvironmentObject` all over the place, and probably triggering redraw on top of redraw.   Some prints using `#function`, `#file` and `#line` might be help you track down exactly what's happening.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll do better next time ^^ for anyone stubeling upon this in the future, in my case adding a coordinate space to the DragGesture fixed this, so working is DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)